# what happens when disk is full when using one disk for multiple macs' time capsule backup

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, backup, time-machine

I'd like to use same external disk for multiple macs time machine backup.

I have a concern that is what will happen when during one macs' backup reaches hdd full capacity.

- Will it give me the option of deleting the oldest backups of any of the mac's or
- will it only dele its own latest backup or
- will just not care of other machines so it will delete random files so making other mac's backup's useless or
- something else

Can you give any references / links?

Thanks

Comment: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18840?locale=en_US & http://www.usatoday.com/story/tech/personal/2015/04/12/apple-time-machine/25675133/ the last link being more realistic, the best words there are excluding internet caches. also on both links excluding applications, that may be much easier to retrieve than users data that only exists on your machine.  As far as Multiple machines using the same disk as backup, i have no idea.

Comment: indications are that a different computer would store in the same folder with the computer/user name creating the variation for the data/files/database.

Comment: I understand what happens when I use single computer with one hdd. What happens when I use multiple?